# The smooth deformation

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

$M$ is a connected smooth manifold and $p$ is a fixed point on $M$. For a null-homotopic smooth loop $\gamma$ at $p$, can we find a smooth deformation, that is, a smooth function $f :[0,1] \times [0,1] \rightarrow M$ such that $f(s,0)=f(s,1)=p$ , $f(1,t)=\gamma(t)$ and $f(0,t)=p$?

Answer (score 1):

There might be some easy proof but I know a proof from the following paper [different versions of MCG](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2221)